# How to extract part of a selected richtextbox line and copy it into a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have this output in a richtextbox

```
0.00001148 - 324.8K
0.00001137 - 452.4K
0.00001125 - 1.4M
0.00001114 - 436.9K
0.00001103 - 111.6K
0.00001092 - 351.8K
0.00001081 - 433.1K
0.00001071 - 320.9K
0.0000106 - 344K
0.0000104 - 9.9K
```

and through the Mouse Click event of the richtextbox I'm using

```
Dim firstcharindex As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()
Dim currentline As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstcharindex)
Dim currentlinetext As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(currentline)
RichTextBox1.Select(firstcharindex, currentlinetext.Length)
```

to select a single line of the RichTextBox.

I want now to extract the first number ( double or decimal ) of the selected line and copy it into a textbox.
E.g. Selecting the line 0.00001148 - 324.8K would send to a textbox the value 0.00001148.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim currentlinechosen As String = Mid(currentlinetext, 1, InStr(currentlinetext, " -") - 1)
    MsgBox(currentlinechosen)
```

Just assign the currentlinechoosen to a textbox

Comment: Thanks that's work! Could you please explain me a bit more how the code is working? How does it split the first part with the second part?

Comment: The instr command finds the specific string location in the current line text ; once you have where this is you use the mid command to start at the first character and end at location character of the returned instr less 1 . . . .  Hope thats clear enough

Comment: so basically if I wanted to get the opposite string, for example input 0.00001148 - 324.8K, output 324.8K I should do like this? `Mid(currentlinetext, -1, InStr(currentlinetext, " -")  1)`

Comment: You just invert the mid command to have the following :-

Dim currentlinechosen2 As String = Mid(currentlinetext, InStr(currentlinetext, " -")+2,100)

The 100 is the length of characters' you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the selected line and convert it to a string of text:

```
dim sel_line as string = currentline.ToString()
```

then extract the first part of the line by splitting it on the  "-":

```
dim temp_string as String() = sel_line.split("-")
```

and then the first index of temp_string will contain your number

```
textbox.text = temp_string(0)
```